# WebConfig Merge AppSettings

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

The situation is this, I want to have a `key` in my `Web.config` that gets changed in my `Web.Debug.config` and my `Web.Release.config` but I am unsure as to how to accomplish this.

I have my `Web.config`:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
```

I'm not sure what my `Web.Debug.config` is meant to be to add a key `key="host" value="somevalue"`, so I've tried this:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="RunningHost" value="http://localhost:55169/" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
</appSettings>
```

This:

```
<appSettings xdt:Transform="Insert">
  <add key="RunningHost" value="http://localhost:55169/" />
</appSettings>
```

This:

```
<appSettings xdt:Transform="Replace">
  <add key="RunningHost" value="http://localhost:55169/" />
</appSettings>
```

To no avail. I read my config like so:

```
var appSetting = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RunningHost"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found out the answer for this.

It's because when I debugged the web project it didn't compile a new config combining the `web.debug.config` with the `web.config`.

However, if you publish it for release then it will combine the `web.release.config` with the `web.config`.

So the simple fix was to put the `RunningHost` in the `web.config`. Then have the release override it!

Answer (score 0):

The first option is correct. Your full Web.Debug.config should look something like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="RunningHost" value="http://localhost:55169/" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

You can right-click on the Web.Debug.config in Solution Explorer and choose Preview Transform to see the transformed output.